# Show that this function is a diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> > Define $\Omega:=\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\overline{B_R}(0)$ with $R>0$ and $n>1$ and $G:=B_R(0)\setminus\left\{0\right\}$ Show that the function
> >     $$
> > \phi\colon \Omega\to G, y=\phi(x):=\frac{R^2}{\lVert x\rVert^2}x
> > $$
> >     is a diffeomorphism and find its inverse.

I did this using n-dim. polar coordinates, because I think it's easier than using cartesian coordinates.

**Proof**

Let $\varphi$ express the transformation to polar coordinates, i.e.
$$
x=\varphi(S,\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_{n-1}).
$$
Then the function $\phi$ can be expressed via
$$
x\mapsto \varphi\left(\frac{R^2}{S},\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_{n-1}\right).
$$

From this it is rather easy to show the bijectivity of $\phi$.

*injectivity*: Consider 
$$
\varphi\left(\frac{R^2}{S},\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_{n-1}\right)=\phi(x_1)=y=\phi(x_2)=\varphi\left(\frac{R^2}{T},\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_{n-1}\right).
$$ 
Then, because $y$ is a point in $G$, which can only be described in polar coordinates in one way, it follows that $x_1=x_2$.

*surjectivity*: Consider any $y\in G$, i.e. $y=\varphi(S,\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_{n-1})$ with $0<S<R$. Then
$$
y=\phi(x), x:=\varphi\left(\frac{R^2}{S},\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_{n-1}\right)
$$
so a preimage is found.

So $\phi$ is injective and surjective and therefore bijective.

It remains to show, that $\phi$ is continiously differentiable and that $\phi^{-1}$ is continiously differentiable.

To see this, one can use, that $\phi$ can be written as the composition of two functions that are continiously differentiable, namely $\varphi\circ T$, where $\varphi$ is again the transformation to polar coordinates (that is indeed continiously differentiable) and T defined by
$$
(S,\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_{n-1})\mapsto (R^2/S,\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_{n-1})
$$,
which is continiously differentiable, too.

Last, but not least, the inverse $\phi^{-1}\colon G\to\Omega$ is given by
$$
y\mapsto \frac{R^2}{\lVert y\rVert^2}y
$$
for $0<\lVert y\rVert<R$.

So it is the same argumentation to show, that $\phi^{-1}$ is continiously differentiable.

All in all: $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism. $\Box$

---

Could you please say me, if my proof is allright?

With greetings,

math12

Comment: If you show $\phi$ is its own inverse (which is easy), you get bijectivity immediately. (And then smoothness implies $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism.)

Comment: Okay, but is my proof okay or wrong?

Comment: And besides that: How can $\phi=\phi^{-1}$ when the domain of the function and its image are different?

Comment: I didn't check your proof carefully, but it looks reasonable. (Regarding your second comment, $\phi$ may be viewed as an involution of $\mathbf{R}^{n}\setminus\{0\}$, and your diffeomorphism is the restriction to an open set.)